# How todo Pylons/Pyramid plugin system?

Tags: python, plugins, pylons, pyramid

Does anyone have any ideas what the best way to make a plugin system for pylons/pyramid? Or may be any example like yapsy-pylons?

Upd:
I wrote an example of yapsy for creating plug-ins in the pylons. I think this approach can be used in other frameworks.
 [pylons_yapsy_plugin](https://github.com/uralbash/pylons_yapsy_plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyramid offers the `config.include('somemodule')` mechanism for allowing addons to configure themselves with your application. It also contains access to the ZCA registry to create plug points for utilities and adapters.

The framework itself is very very unopinionated and flexible and so you could probably use something like yapsy if you didn't like the 2 options I mentioned above. The key to writing any sort of plugin is to figure out your constraints and work from there toward one of those solutions.